# Why doesn't xargs in parallel mode work with grep?

Tags: linux, xargs

```
cat gg
```

gives

```
192
```

and

```
cat tmpfilelist
```

gives

```
android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/src_assets_images_alerts_iconnotificationsmartpluggreen.png
android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/src_assets_images_ic_biggames.png  
android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/src_assets_images_alerts_iconnotificationsmartpluggreen.png  
android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/src_assets_images_ic_biggames.png   
android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi  /src_assets_images_alerts_iconnotificationsmartpluggreen.png  
android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/src_assets_images_ic_biggames.png  
gg  
ios/WebRTC.framework/Headers/RTCCallbackLogger.h  
ios/WebRTC.framework/Headers/RTCFileLogger.h  
ios/WebRTC.framework/Headers/RTCLogging.h
```

I run xargs with parralel mode on - this does not find the required text "192":

```
cat tmpfilelist | \xargs   -P0 -t  -I {} \bash  -c "\grep -C 2 -H -I -r 192 {}" |& \grep -C 3 "192 gg"
bash -c '\grep -C 2 -H -I -r 192 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/src_assets_images_ic_biggames.png'  
bash -c '\grep -C 2 -H -I -r 192 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/src_assets_images_alerts_iconnotificationsmartpluggreen.png'  
bash -c '\grep -C 2 -H -I -r 192 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdp/src_assets_images_ic_biggames.png'  
bash -c '\grep -C 2 -H -I -r 192 gg'
bash -c '\grep -C 2 -H -I -r 192 ios/WebRTC.framework/Headers/RTCCallbackLogger.h'  
bash -c '\grep -C 2 -H -I -r 192 ios/WebRTC.framework/Headers/RTCFileLogger.h'  
bash -c '\grep -C 2 -H -I -r 192 ios/WebRTC.framework/Headers/RTCLogging.h'
```

---

When I disable parralel mode it succesfully finds the text "192" in file "gg":

```
cat tmpfilelist | \xargs   -t  -I {} \bash  -c "\grep -C 2 -H -I -r 192 {}" |& \grep -C 3 "192 gg"
bash -c '\grep -C 2 -H -I -r 192 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/src_assets_images_ic_biggames.png'  
bash -c '\grep -C 2 -H -I -r 192 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/src_assets_images_alerts_iconnotificationsmartpluggreen.png'  
bash -c '\grep -C 2 -H -I -r 192 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdp/src_assets_images_ic_biggames.png'  
bash -c '\grep -C 2 -H -I -r 192 gg'  
gg:192  
bash -c '\grep -C 2 -H -I -r 192 ios/WebRTC.framework/Headers/RTCCallbackLogger.h'  
bash -c '\grep -C 2 -H -I -r 192 ios/WebRTC.framework/Headers/RTCFileLogger.h'
```

Any reason why parallel mode would break grep? Or have I made a mistake somwhere?

Many thanks

Comment: Anyone have any idea?

Comment: Can you clarify few points (1) why use grep on binary file (2) why wrap the 'grep` inside 'bash ...` (3) what is the required output (list of matching files ?)?

Comment: @dash-o 
(1) that was unintentional
(2) Wrapping commands inside the bash command alows xargs to execute multiple function.
(3) Look at the snippet after "When I disable parralel mode it succesfully finds the text "192" in file "gg":"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is indeed due to the parallel execution. The issue is that the output is not deterministic when the you run it in parallel. I create a similar test

```sh
bash-5.0# ls -alh
total 32K
drwxr-xr-x    9 root     root         288 May 20 17:00 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        4.0K May 20 17:11 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           3 May 20 17:00 a
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           3 May 20 17:00 b
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           3 May 20 17:00 c
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           4 May 20 17:00 d
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           3 May 20 17:00 e
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           3 May 20 17:00 f
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          11 May 20 17:00 files

bash-5.0# tail -n +1 *
==> a <==
192
==> b <==
193
==> c <==
192
==> d <==
195

==> e <==
200
==> f <==
198
==> files <==
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

Now if we run your two commands without the last grep the outputs are like below

**Without parallel**

```sh
bash-5.0# cat files | \xargs   -t  -I {} \bash  -c "\grep -C 2 -H -I -r 192 {}"
bash -c \grep -C 2 -H -I -r 192 a
a:192
bash -c \grep -C 2 -H -I -r 192 b
bash -c \grep -C 2 -H -I -r 192 c
c:192
bash -c \grep -C 2 -H -I -r 192 d
bash -c \grep -C 2 -H -I -r 192 e
bash -c \grep -C 2 -H -I -r 192 f
```

**With Parallel**

```sh
bash-5.0# cat files | \xargs  -P4 -t  -I {} \bash  -c "\grep -C 2 -H -I -r 192 {}"
bash -c \grep -C 2 -H -I -r 192 a
bash -c \grep -C 2 -H -I -r 192 b
bash -c \grep -C 2 -H -I -r 192 c
bash -c \grep -C 2 -H -I -r 192 d
bash -c \grep -C 2 -H -I -r 192 e
a:192
bash -c \grep -C 2 -H -I -r 192 f
c:192
```

Hope you can see how it is affecting the output and orders of your line. So your issue is that when you do `grep -C 3 192 gg`, you are supposed to get 3 lines before printing of `192 gg` and 3 after, which you actually do get.

But `gg:192` is printed sometime later because of each command sending their output in parallel on the same output terminal

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer - but pointing to possible problem.

The code runs two filters in pipeline

- grep -C 2 -H -I -r 192 FILENAMe
- grep -C 3 "192 gg"

The output from the first line will follow the format 'FILENAME:DATA'. In the example above

```
gg:192
```

The second filter is not going to find the pattern '192 gg'.

So the question may be how does the non-parallel produces any output ?

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer

Your final `grep -C 3` requests 3 lines of context around the `192 gg`.  In the parallel case, this might or might not be enough to find the line containing `gg:192`.

### Details

Before the final `grep`, your output will consist of a number of lines like:

```
bash -c \grep -C 2 -H -I -r 192 <filename>
```

which are echoed to stderr just before `xargs` launches each `bash -c ...` command, and the line

```
gg:192
```

is echoed to stdout when the relevant `bash -c ...` command (i.e. the one involving the file `gg`) finds the match.

In the parallel case, the whole output that is piped into your the final `grep` (once stderr and stdout are combined using `|&`) might look something like this, where I have replaced the other filenames for brevity:

```
bash -c \grep -C 2 -H -I -r 192 some_file
bash -c \grep -C 2 -H -I -r 192 some_other_file
bash -c \grep -C 2 -H -I -r 192 another_file
bash -c \grep -C 2 -H -I -r 192 gg
bash -c \grep -C 2 -H -I -r 192 and_another_file
bash -c \grep -C 2 -H -I -r 192 yet_another_file
gg:192
bash -c \grep -C 2 -H -I -r 192 and_yet_another_file
```

In this example, the `bash -c ...` commands involving `and_another_file` and `yet_another_file` were launched *after* the one involving `gg` was launched, but before the one involving `gg` wrote its output (or at least, before any stdio buffers associated with that output were flushed), so they appear between the lines containing `192 gg` and `gg:192`.

The number of such intervening lines between the lines containing `192 gg` and the `gg:192` (in this example, 2) will depend on timings and the number of other parallel tasks being launched after the one involving `gg`.  This will vary, and for example if you inserted a `sleep` statement (e.g. `... \bash -c "sleep 1; \grep -C ...`) then there would tend to be more such lines.  In any case, you are then piping it to a `grep -C 3` to extract 3 lines of context.  If it so happens that there are fewer than 3 intervening lines, then this `grep -C` will find the line containing `gg:192`, but if there are 3 or more, then it will be outside the requested amount of context and will not be in the final output.

In the serial case, however, the `gg:192` line is guaranteed to always be immediately after the `192 gg` line, as follows:

```
bash -c \grep -C 2 -H -I -r 192 some_file
bash -c \grep -C 2 -H -I -r 192 some_other_file
bash -c \grep -C 2 -H -I -r 192 another_file
bash -c \grep -C 2 -H -I -r 192 gg
gg:192
bash -c \grep -C 2 -H -I -r 192 and_another_file
bash -c \grep -C 2 -H -I -r 192 yet_another_file
bash -c \grep -C 2 -H -I -r 192 and_yet_another_file
```

and so it is always within the 3 lines of context.